# Git Repositories missing from Team Explorer Everywhere when connecting to Azure DevOps 2019

Tags: azure-devops, team-explorer-everywhere

I've connected Eclipse 2018-12 with the latest version of Team Explorer Everywhere to a project on my Azure DevOps 2019 Server RC2.  When I go to Team Explorer and connect to my Project I do not see the "Git Repositories" menu option.  The only options I have are Work Items, Builds, Settings.

[image]

Reading a tutorial online I see that I should have the Git Repositories option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/java/labs/eclipsegit/?view=azure-devops-2019

[image]

I am able to see the Git repos for the project via the web, and check them out with the command line git.

[image]

I have tried this with several projects on my server and I can't see Git Repositories for any of them in TEE.  Am I doing something wrong?  Should I just use File->Import to check out from Git and avoid Team Explorer?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue with Eclipse and TEE 14.134.

Answer (score 2):

Try uninstalling the TEE Language Pack. I was having the same issue on one Eclipse instance (2019-06) and not the other (2019-03).  Comparing the two I decided to remove the TEE Language Pack from the one that was not working.  After uninstalling the TEE Language Pack I was able to see the Git repositories.